# Django Fulltext search on JSON field

Tags: json, django, postgresql, full-text-search

I am trying to implement the newly added Fulltext-search Postgres support for [Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/).

One of the fields I'm trying to search on is a JSON field:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
class Product():
        attributes = JSONField(...)
```

If I try to do the following search using a [SearchVector](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvector)

```
Product.objects.annotate(
    search=SearchVector('attributes'),
).filter(search=keyword)
```

Will raise:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: ...ol1, to_tsvector(COALESCE("product"."attributes", '')) AS "s...
                                                         ^
DETAIL:  The input string ended unexpectedly.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1:
```

Which makes sense, a raw SQL query like this will need to be

```
select to_tsvector(attributes::text) from product;
```

But how can I achieve that field conversion inside Django syntax ?

Comment: @e4c5 yes, you'll need to use raw SQL queries inside Django.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @e4c5 reported there's [Cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) function since [Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/) (the same version you used).

So if you would to search a JSON field as text you have to cast it as text:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
from django.db.models import TextField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

Product.objects.annotate(
    search=SearchVector(Cast('attributes', TextField())),
).filter(search=keyword)
```

You can also use only specific part of your JSON field in your SearchVector:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTextTransform

Product.objects.annotate(
    search=SearchVector(KeyTextTransform('key1', 'attributes')),
).filter(search=keyword)
```

PostgreSQL 10 added [Full Text Search support for JSON and JSONB](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/New_in_postgres_10#Full_Text_Search_support_for_JSON_and_JSONB).

Comment: i note that your gripe against raw queries is because they are not portable. Please note the. your code became non portable to other databases the moment you imported from django.contrib.postgres

Comment: Actually the official Django Documentation invite everyone to avoid RawSQL if possible.
The motivations are not only related to portability and DRY but also to security.
I invite you to read it:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.RawSQL

Comment: It's rather inaccurate to say that Raw SQL is insecure. What is insecure is string munging instead of passing parameters.

Comment: @e4c5 I never wrote RawSQL is insecure in general BUT in the documentation page I linked you can read this Waring about security:
"To protect against SQL injection attacks, you must escape any parameters that the user can control by using params. params is a required argument to force you to acknowledge that you’re not interpolating your SQL with user-provided data."
You can read the other parts about SQL injection on the link above.

Comment: Anyway I don't want to continue to speak about RawSQL in general.
I proposed my solution to the problem using only the Django ORM and I suggest everyone to use this solution instead of using RawSQL in every situation it's possible.
If you want to use RawSQL to do the same thing you can do with the Django ORM you are free to do it but I'm free to don't agree with this solution.
BTW thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

### Why you shouldn't do this

The very reason that [JSONB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-json.html) data type and [JSON/JSONB functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) were introduced was to avoid this kind of search! The Django ORM provides access to most of this functionality. The [Func expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) can be used to for functionality that cannot quite be reached with the double underscore notation etc.

If on the other hand you have a large text field in your JSONB column that really does need to be full text searched. This indicates that the database design isn't optimal. That field should be pulled out of the JSON and it should be a field on it's own right.

### If you still want to do this

Django 1.10 just added a [Cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) function.

> class Cast(expression, output_field)
>    Forces the result type of
>   expression to be the one from output_field.

If you are on an older version of Django you can use the RawSQL function. You will find an example on the same page linked above. Please note that the use of the RawSQL function is not the same as executing a raw query.

### Update Jan 2018

There is a certain belief that using RawSQL will make your code non portable and you should never use it. This question deals with the django.contrib.postgres package, your code most definitely isn't portable. So if you want to avoid raw sql, it should be for a reason other than portability.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but I think it's important for readers to know that PostgreSQL 10 has added [Full Text Search support for JSON and JSONB](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/New_in_postgres_10#Full_Text_Search_support_for_JSON_and_JSONB) so first the sentence in this answer is not correct today.

Related to the use of RawSQL the official Django Documentation remark to avoid it [Raw SQL expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.RawSQL)

Comment: Actually the Django's Documentation at the exact paragraph I linked you can read, about RawSQL expression,  *"These extra lookups may not be portable to different database engines (because you’re explicitly writing SQL code) and violate the DRY principle, so you should avoid them if possible."* . And in my answer I demonstrated how to solve the question without RawSQL.

Comment: Note that it says avoid if possible. While I am a huge fan of the Django ORM, and use it all the time for complex queries. I don't think there's ever any need to tie oneself up in knots when a simple raw query does the trick. If you are using JSONB you don't need to be worried about whether your raw query is compatible with sqlite or mysql. JSONB itself isn't compatible with either of those.

Comment: I agree with you but in this particular case you can execute the query using the Django ORM only, so is possible to avoid RawSQL. Off cours your suggestion tu use Cast is still valid.

Comment: Where does it say avoid if possible?

Comment: @yekta These extra lookups may not be portable to different database engines (because you’re explicitly writing SQL code) and violate the DRY principle, so you should avoid them if possible.

Comment: @yekta JSON and JSONB are not portable so it's pointless debating whether you shouldn't use raw sql to keep the project portable

Comment: @yekta I explained why avoid RawSQL in a comment unnder my answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835167/django-fulltext-search-on-json-field/47487209?noredirect=1#comment83909540_47487209

Comment: @e4c5 the point is that you can solve the problem using only Django ORM (I demonstrated it in my answer) and the documentation ask you to avoid RawSQL "if possible", so why, in this case, you want still use RawSQL if is not necessary ? (BTW my question is not a general but related only to this Question)